# Show elements after scroll, one after the other

Tags: jquery

I have some images to show on a page, and I would like them to be delayed on scroll.

```
<div>
<img src="A.jpg" class="hidden"> <img src="B.jpg" class="hidden">
...
<img src="C.jpg" class="hidden"> <img src="D.jpg" class="hidden">
</div>
```

After scrolling the page, I need the elements (on the same line) to appear one by one. As the function is based on elements position, if elements have the same vertical position they appear at the same time, which I don't want. If I have 3 images on the same line, I want them to appear one after the other.

Next, when the page is scrolled again, the script check again if there are new elements, and show them one by one with a 500ms delay.

```
<script>
    /* every time the window is scrolled ... */
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        show();
    });
    function show (){
        /* Check the location of each element */
        $('.hidden').each(function(index) {
            var visibility = $(this).css('opacity')
            var size = ($(this).outerHeight());
            var object = $(this).offset().top + size;
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* If the object is not visible yet, and it's position is now scrolled */
            if (visibility == 0) {
                if (bottom_of_window > object) {
                    $(this).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 500);
                }
            }
        });
    };
</script>
```

I've tried to add a delay on it :

```
var time = 500;
/*...*/
$(this).delay(time).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 500);
time = time + 500;
```

But it delays the 3 images (all the line) at the same time, not each after the previous one.

I've tried using the index to have something like `time = index*100` but it doesn't work with a fast/big scroll, the index grows too much and the results vary from 0.1s to few seconds ... It doesn't work either for me with `settimeout`.

Example with few images :

http://jsfiddle.net/24M3n/1654/

How can I include a proper delay in this each() function? 
Thanks for any help !

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what do you want to achieve? You want the images in the same row appear at the same time? For example if there are 2 in a row, they appear at the same time as a row, not one by one.

Comment: No, exactly the opposite, without delay() they appear at the same time, and with delay() I can't find a way to get it properly, like each image of the line every 500ms.

Comment: And you don't want the next row to appear until the previous one is done animating ( one by one, 500 ms apart ), correct?

Comment: Right, and only if the scroll is far enough in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I found :

```
var elementPosition,bottomWindow,lastPosition,delay=0;
    $('.hiddenelement').each(function () {
        elementTopPosition= $(this).offset().top;
        bottomWindow= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();    
        // If the object is visible in the window
        if (bottomWindow > elementTopPosition ) {
            //if element is on the same line than the previous one, add a delay
            if(elementTopPosition == lastPosition){
                delay=delay+250;
            }
            else{
                //reset delay if it is a different line
                delay=0;
            }
            lastPosition=elementTopPosition ;
            //show element with the appropriate delay
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).show('slow');   
            },delay);
        };
    });
```

The idea is the same, I've just took top element position instead of bottom, delay is shorter, and action on element changed a bit (edit css `opacity` VS jQuery function `hide()`)